# Define the condition on the parameter $ \ a \ $ such that the equation has solution .

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the equation of the PDE $ \ \sqrt x y u_x+yu_y=u \ $  with $ \ u(s,a \sqrt s)=1 , \ and  \  \ x,y,s >0 \ $. Define the condition on the parameter $ \ a \ $ such that the equation  has   solution .

**Answer:**

The Lagrange's auxiliary equation is

$ \frac{dx}{\sqrt x y}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{du}{u} \ $

From the first two fraction , we get

$ \ y=2 \sqrt x+A, \ ..............(1) , \  \ A=constant \ $

From the last two equation, we get

$ \log u=\log y+ B , \ B=constant \\  \Rightarrow \frac{u}{y}=B \\ \Rightarrow u=C y , \ \ C=e^B \ ........(2) $

From (1) and (2) , we have

$ \frac{u}{y}=F(y-2 \sqrt x ) , \ \ F =arbitrary \ \ function\ \\ or, \ u(x,y)=y * F(y-2 \sqrt x ) $

**But how can I find the condition on the parameter $ \ a \ $ ?**

**Is there any help ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$u(x,y)=yF(y-2\sqrt{x}) \tag 1$$
Condition :

$1=u(s,a\sqrt {s})=a\sqrt {s}F(a\sqrt {s}-2\sqrt{s}) \quad\to\quad a\sqrt {s}F\big((a-2)\sqrt{s}\big) =1$

This implies $a\neq 0$ because if $a=0$ then $0=1$ which is impossible.

Also this implies $a\neq 2$ because if $a=2$ then $2\sqrt {s}F(0) =1\quad\to\quad \sqrt {s}=$constant, which is impossible.

Solution in case of $a\neq 0$ and $a\neq 2$ :

Let $X=(a-2)\sqrt{s} \quad\to\quad \sqrt{s}=\frac{X}{a-2} \quad\to\quad a\sqrt {s}F\big((a-2)\sqrt{s}\big) =1=a\frac{X}{a-2}F(X)$

The function $F(X)$ is determined :
$$F(X)=\frac{a-2}{aX}$$
Putting it into $(1)$ with $X=y-2\sqrt{x}$ leads to :
$$u(x,y)=\frac{a-2}{a}\frac{y}{(y-2\sqrt{x})}\qquad \begin{cases}a\neq 0\\a\neq 2 \end{cases}$$